# Jest cannot find module during execution of unit test

Tags: angular, jestjs, babel-jest

I use jest framwork for testing my Angular application.
When I run the npm test command I get an error message that say :

Cannot find module 'src/environments/environment' from 'src/app/services/applicant/applicant.service.ts'

It's seem that jest not found directory where services are define.
I changed my jest config to define the root module path but always down.

Please find bellow my package.json and jest config file.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "eslint --quiet --cache .",
    "lint-fix": "npm run lint -- --fix"
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleDirectories": ["node_modules", "src"]
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/material": "^16.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.8",
    "@angular/router": "^16.2.8",
    "@azure/msal-angular": "^3.0.5",
    "@azure/msal-browser": "^3.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "chart.js": "^4.4.0",
    "export-from-json": "^1.7.3",
    "jest-config": "^29.7.0",
    "mdb-angular-ui-kit": "^5.1.0",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^12.0.2",
    "primeng": "^16.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.1",
    "tslib": "^2.6.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/jest": "^16.0.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^16.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.2.8",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.5.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.5",
    "chromium": "^3.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.51.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^27.4.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "npx": "^3.0.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.6"
  }
}
```

jest-config.js:

```
const {defaults} = require('jest-config');

module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: ["src/**/*.ts"],
  modulePaths: [ "<rootDir>/src" ]
}
```

Best regards